# Detect native app installed from iOS Google Chrome Browser

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I am trying to detect native apps that is not implemented by me on my web page and there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200) to Safari Mobile. The solution mentioned two methods

1. Detect appInstalled cookie: My web page cannot assume every app placed an appInstalled cookie when their app is installed or after users erased history; therefore, my web page cannot use this method.
2. Use javascript setTimeout to display a fallback page when it can actually timeout without going to the native app. This works perfectly on Safari; however, Chrome will ignore the timeout and display page not found for un-handled custom scheme(i.e. app not installed)

Is there a way to detect native app installed on iOS Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this question:

[How can I open app url with fallback from Chrome for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298205/how-can-i-open-app-url-with-fallback-from-chrome-for-ios?rq=1)

Based on the above answer from ajwillia.ms in the link above, here is the function to display fallback page while trying to ope native app from Chrome for iOS.

```
// url is your app custom scheme.
// fallback is theaddress of fallback page.
// assumption: you are sure this is executing in Chrome for iOS.
function redirectTo_chrome_ios(url, fallback)
{
    //open a new tab to open the native app
    my_window = window.open(url, "_blank");
    //close the tab after some time 
    setTimeout(function(){ my_window.close(); }, 500);
    //redirect to fallback page regardless
    window.location = fallback;
}
```